# Triggering a link if wrapped in an <em> tag

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue where a modal isn't triggering if it is wrapped in an  tag.
In my example, if you click in the "normal" font-style part of the link, it fires properly, if you click where the italics are, it won't.

Any ideas?

JS

```
$(function () {
  const openModals = [];
  $('.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.target).attr('href')).show());
  });
  $(window).add('.close').click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal, .close')) {
      const closing = openModals.pop().addClass('modal-content-active');
      setTimeout(() => {closing.hide().removeClass('modal-content-active')}, 0);
      if (openModals.length > 0) {
        openModals[openModals.length - 1].removeClass('open');
      } else $('body').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/h70bkej9/30/)

Answer (score 1):

in the first event handler, you are referencing the "target" and not the "currentTarget"

`e.target` represents the exact element being clicked - in your case the `<em/>` - while `e.currentTarget` represents the element *the event handler is attached to*, which is where your `href` value is.

I'd change the two references to `e.target` in the first event handler to `e.currentTarget` and things should work as expected.

```
  $('.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.currentTarget).attr('href')).show());
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7o6f9su/

Comment: this did it. Seems a bit cleaner to do this, as opposed to adding a href to each <em> tag.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/qLpcfx8k/
You just need to pass the same href to the  tag and be happy :)

```
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">This is the trigger <em href="#myModal1"> for the first modal</em></a><br>
<a href="#myModal3" class="modal-button">This is the trigger <em href="#myModal1"> for the second modal</em></a>
```